# Show a parallelogram is a rhombus

Tags: geometry

> If $ABCD$ is a parallelogram with $\angle BAD=60 ^\circ$ and $\dfrac{AC^2}{BD^2}=\dfrac31$, show $ABCD$ is a rhombus.

[image]

We have the squares of $AC$ and $BD$ so MAYBE it is a good idea to construct right triangles. Let $DD_1\perp AB$ and $CC_1 \perp AB$. Now we have the right triangles $BD_1D$ and $AC_1C$ with hypotenuses $BD$ and $AC$, respectively. By the Pythagorean theorem we can get $AC^2=AC_1^2+CC_1^2$ and $BD^2=BD_1^2+DD_1^2$. This does not seem to help. Can you give me some hints? Thank you in advane! :)

Comment: If https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines is allowed, we can use on $$\angle BAD, \angle ADC$$ to find $$AD=DC$$

Comment: Law of coines is not allowed. :) Thank you for the response though.

Answer (score 1):

Let take $E$ on right side of the line segment $AB$ such that $|DB|=|CE|=k$ . Then $CBE$ will be equilateral triangle so, $|CC_1|=\frac{\sqrt{3}k}{2}$ that gives us $\angle CAB=30^{\circ}$ thus $|CB|=|AB|$ hence, $ABCD$ is rhombus

Comment: Thank you for the response! I did not understand where to take $E$. On $AB$ such that $DB=CE$?

Comment: the place that satisfies $|BC_1|=|C_1E|$

Comment: @KnowledgeGreedy on line segment of $AB$ but on right side